# SQL to LING Convert

Tags: sql, linq

```
SELECT * FROM STK_Trans 
WHERE STORETO =2199 and STOREFR = 2199 and TRANSDT
BETWEEN '01/01/2023' AND '01/05/2023'
```

Can anyone convert this sql comment to linq?

```
from u in db.STK_Trans
where u.STORETO == stto &&
u.STOREFR == stid &&
(u.TRANSDT >= datefrom &&
 u.TRANSDT <= dateto) select u;
```

I use this but not working

Comment: Please explain what "not working" means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
var query = from u in db.STK_Trans
            where u.STORETO == 2199 &&
                  u.STOREFR == 2199 &&
                  u.TRANSDT >= new DateTime(2023, 1, 1) &&
                  u.TRANSDT <= new DateTime(2023, 1, 5)
            select u;
```